# Phusion passenger - Gemfile.lock Permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger, gemfile

I'm running a Rails application on Phusion passenger and I get a `Permission denied - Gemfile.lock` error message often. I fix it by running `bundle update` but it keeps on popping up the same error every few days (I do not make any changes to the application). What could be causing it?

Comment: do you deploy with a different user from the one running passenger?

Comment: I run `bundle update` with `sudo`. Then it works fine for a while. After a few days it will give the same error again without me touching anything.

Comment: I have a few applications running at the same time and only this one has this problem. I just recreated the application, let's see if it's a problem with the application itself...